# Jquery- reload doesnt occur if clicked second time

Tags: jquery, reload

```
<li id="rpt21" align=left><a  class="keepopen" href="#">Trade List Buys</a></li>
```

If i click on the above link 'Trade List Buys', the list gets loaded in the right side of the screen. however, when i click again while on the same page, it doesnt reload the data on right side. it looks static. How can i ensure that it reloads every time i click.

Below is the rpt21 function which gets executed.

```
$("#rpt21 a.keepopen").click(function() {
    $("#report_panel").hide();
    $("#report_header").hide();
    $("#report_panel_alldata").hide();
    $("#report_header_alldata").hide();
    var rmanager = $("#rmanager").val();
    var manager = $("#manager").val();
    var account = $("#account").val();
    var folderdate = $("#folderdate").val();
    var pricedate = $("#pricedate").val();;
    x = getDataForRpt(rmanager, manager, account, folderdate, pricedate, "buy_list", "D:\\web\\webtmp", "post_op_rpt_20150617_4700.html", "runRpt");
    $("#report_panel").show();
});
```

Comment: I do not see any issue with the code. Can you place an alert or console.log as the first line in the function and confirm the status?

Comment: Off topic: You can combine selectors in many jQuery methods, including `hide()`. Simply list them with commas between.

Comment: There are other functions too along with this rpt21 function. All these functions are inside 
$(document).ready(function(){ rpt21(); rpt22(); and so on}

Could you please let me know where to put the above code and what to write instead of document ?


@Nikhil - I added console.log(). This command gets executed everytime i click which confirms that the function runs. however visual display of data on right side remains same. it doesnt blink and upload again or anything of that sort

Answer (score 1):

*It is working first time* not after that, This can happen if you are recreating the DOM elements.

In this scenario you can use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click', "#rpt21 a.keepopen", function(){
    //Your code
});
```